# Quicker way to manage a form request that needs to search a file to return a result

Tags: php, linux

I have a file that contains info that I need to return according to a form submission.

e.g

User submits a name and I look for that name in the file and return the info corresponding to the name in the file to the user.

It sounds silly but I can't use an SQL database. So I need to use php directly, but for high load and large data(~1Million rows) the time taken is too much.

I'd like a solution and one of the possible solutions is to run a php script save sort/save/hash all data and then query the sorted data but I know of no way to do this.
 
(Obviously I do not want to fire up the interpreter repeatedly and form the table/sort repeatedly I need to run it once and then repeatedly query it) But I have no Idea how to achieve this or where to start.

Comment: You should consider using MongoDB for such amounts of data

Comment: You need to search through a million records, and can't use a database? Ouch! Is the data pretty much static, or is it updated pretty constantly? If it's static, I'd suggest breaking it down into numerous smaller files, so you can just search through the one you need - ie a file just containing all the names starting with 'A', 'B', and so on.

Comment: The data is static, but there are multiple fields.
User can search for any of the fields and I need to return all the others corresponding to it.
And I could sort according to all the fields and divide but it'd get messy.

Comment: @redskins80 I don't have any sort of privileges to install anything that require root permissions, so I can't use any sort of Databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If it's static, I'd suggest breaking it down into numerous smaller files, so you can just search through the one you need - ie a file just containing all the names starting with 'A', 'B', and so on. – andrewsi

As @andrewsi said, the best approach seems to be to break it up into some sort of sub records based on some logical structure and then query the sub records.

---

I still haven't found out how to setup the sorted/hashed Data Structure and query it repeatedly without firing up the interpreter over and over (Although I do realise that would essentially be the same as creating some sort of an elementary DB/DBMS)

So for now the solution is to use a predetermined file structure/organisation.